# Dynamic binding Gridview not update using Update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using GridView to show data in asp.net application and data are dynamically bind in cs side code.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional"  runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                    </Columns>  
                </asp:GridView>  
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButton1" EventName="Click"/></Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

there is no problem but when I update my GridView using Update Panel then it append new data to old data show in GridView.
https://www.diigo.com/item/image/41snq/s18c

My cs side code is :

```
DataTable dt = _oBase.FillDataTable("Exec sp_Detail");
DataTable dtC = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new[] { "TimeName" }); // Filter Row Name

DataTable dtH;
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dtH = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
               let tags = row.Field<string>("ColumnName")
               orderby tags ascending
               select row).CopyToDataTable();
        dtH = dtH.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new[] { "ColumnName" }); // Filter Column Name
    }
    else
    {
        dtH = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new[] { "ColumnName" });
    }

    var tFf = new TemplateField { HeaderTemplate = new MyGridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, "_", dtC, dt) };
    //tFF.HeaderText = "";
    tFf.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "mGrid";
    tFf.ItemTemplate = new MyGridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, "", dtC, dt);
    tFf.ItemStyle.Width = 50;
    grdView.Columns.Add(tFf);

    for (int i = 0; i < dtH.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var tF = new TemplateField { HeaderText = dtH.Rows[i][0].ToString() };
        tF.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "mGrid";
        tF.ItemTemplate = new MyGridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, dtH.Rows[i][0].ToString(), dtC, dt);
        tF.ItemStyle.Width = 130;
        grdView.Columns.Add(tF);
    }

    grdView.DataSource = dtC;
    grdView.DataBind();
```

Comment: how are you updating your grid? can you post that part of code?

Answer (score 0):

I feel i have had the problem you describe a few times. In my case it's always because of a bind in Page_Load running on every load, any method you run from hmm let say a button click, runs before the Page_Load so you need to wrap the initial bind in a if test

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Dont bind outside as it will overwrite the BindCode() 
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Bind inhere then it wil only bind on a full refresh and not on AJAX (partial postbacks)
    }
}

public void BindCode(){
}
```

Comment: According to you I use !IsPostBack method and then bind data on OnClick method. Is it right? If it is right then I also use Ispostback method but still problem same.

Comment: I think some view state information of gridview not delete and new data append in old gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `UpdateMode="Conditional"` for your update panel, are you using the line 
`UpdatePanel2.Update();` anywhere in your code?

If you aren't, you may want to consider `UpdateMode="Always"` or including the .Update() call in your code at some point.  With conditional updating, you have to manually fire the Update() method in your code behind.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes you are right, I am not using UpdatePanel2.Update(); in code side so I change it to UpdateMode="Always". but same problem appear in GridView .

Comment: I got solution to set  EnableViewState="False" in GridView control property. Thank to all..